# Magic tag cleanup effort requested

Tags: discussion

[magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) has received a lot of questions lately and it is now our #1 game tag (#4 overall).  I'd like for the top users of that tag to get together and update the tag info to reflect the way we'd like the tag to be used and [what it means to us](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

Currently the [tag info](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-the-gathering/info) is pretty generic and just says some bland corporate stuff about the game.

A couple things that I think could be addressed would be:

- questions to avoid (fix my deck, others?)
- Should mentioned cards have images right in the post?  Should we link out to them?  if so, where?
- A list of good general resources for people wanting more information about MtG
- what else?

I'm hoping that users who are more in tune with the current MtG scene that I am can run with this question.  If this works out well, I'd love to extend a template to other popular games on this site and really get their tag wikis looking great too.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps also it would be worth adding [mtg] as a synonym tag.

Comment: @shujaa - this has been done.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a rework to the edit queue, I hope that it gives someone else a good starting point for polishing into a useful tag wiki.